# For-loop modulo operator

Tags: powershell, modulo

I have to take an exam tomorrow, and one of the practice questions is as follows:

```
for ($i = 3; $i++; $i %= 9) { Write-Host $i }
```

The answer to this question should be that the lowest possible number from this line equals 4, and the highest number equals 9.

However, if you ask me, the highest number would be 8? Because when the $i becomes 9 the calculation results in a 0?

Please correct me if (obviously) wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will print a `9` as well. **[`For loop.`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_loop)**.

```
for (INITIALIZATION; CONDITION; AFTERTHOUGHT) {..}
```

`AFTERTHOUGHT` is executed at the **END** of the loop. So, it will execute that `Write-Host 9` and then execute `i = 9 % 9` *= 0*, at which point, the condition which is then checked becomes false.

---

Additionally:

`i++` being post-increment is the reason why the condition check shows a 0 and exits the loop.
If it had been a `++i`, there would be an infinite loop there.

Comment: Meaning the {} block gets executed BEFORE the Afterthought ? Makes sense. I guess that mean the 0 doesn't get Written to host for the fact that it states in the initialization that $i = 3 ?

Comment: Yes. That is correct. Initialization occurs at the very beginning.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks alot! May I however ask you another small thing in the time I wait to approve your answer? 

My book states that a Syntax error in a PowerShell script is not a terminating error. I presume this is becausse it searches for those errors before executing ?

Comment: @SiemHermans Try making a typo in your above statement. The error will be thrown, but the `for` loop will continue to execute. The error can be caught and handled if need be. It just means that execution is not halted due to syntax errors.